# Tesseract bounding box distance calculation

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

[image: cropped_im][image]

I am trying to apply tesseract OCR to extract text from an image. At first, I tried image_to_data, which returned text but in some cases, it gave mispled char. Then I tried image_to_boxes which returned each char very correctly. But my problem is, I need to concatenate those characters to make full words. Can anyone suggest to me any idea how can I do this? I meant to say that I need to make three words from this dictionary such as "~Phone" , ":", "+88-02-5042248-50".

And finally, can anyone please explain what does mean by left, bottom, right, and top in this dictionary? Can I use them for finding distance between two char?

Comment: Can you upload your image?

Comment: @CodingPeter, Just added cropped_im image. I want to extract text from this image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
# Load image
image = cv2.imread('muTYX.jpg')

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang = 'eng', config='--psm 7 --oem 3 ')

text = (text.split('\n'))
print(text[0].split(' '))
```

Output: ['Phone', ':', '+88-02-55042248-50']

And the dictionary of `image_to_boxes` is like:

```
#(index of character, start x-axis, start y-axis, end x-axis, end y-axis)
P 53 50 64 76 0 
h 63 50 75 77 0
...
```

There is more info in the following website : https://nanonets.com/blog/ocr-with-tesseract/

Comment: Thank you so much @CodingPeter. you just saved my day

Comment: Glad to hear that, hope you can learn more successful. BTW you can click the tick from my answer if it's useful to you, so that other people who has the same question can see this solution.